# JavaScript function for jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I've been Googling for the past 2 days trying to figure out how to add events to my tabs, but I'm having trouble getting any of the solutions to work. I'm completely over my head with this stuff, so please include simple explanations. What I have so far are some tabs (in which I just copied and pasted):

```
<div id="tabs" role="tabpanel">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" aria-controls="Active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Active</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabs-2" aria-controls="Inactive" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Inactive</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabs-3" aria-controls="Retired" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Retired</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Active"></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Inactive"></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Retired"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also copied and pasted a JavaScript function that looks unlike any other JavaScript function I've dealt with and it doesn't work(the alert statement is never fired):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
      activate: function (event, ui) {
        var $activeTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        if ($activeTab == 1) {
          alert(Tab 1!);
        }

        if ($activeTab == 2){}
        if ($activeTab == 3){}  
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm using the Spring MVC and my intention is to send the value of the tab back to the controller through a JavaScript function (as I see no other way around it). Based on that value, a table on the page is populated with certain data ('modules' in this case). I've created a controller method and I'm not sure whether it should be get or post or how to get the tab values in there. Here's my attempted controller method code:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/update")
public final String changeTab(final ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "id") String id) {
    System.out.println(id);
    //model.addAttribute("modules", moduleDao.sortStatus(status));
    return "module/admin";
}
```

What can I do to my code to achieve this? Am I even on the right track? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with you tab creation html. Attached is your modified code that works when I gave it a try. You were missing id attribute on tab div that should match href. Hope this helps with the jQuery part.

W.r.t to the second question on binding with spring, now that you have event handler attached to your tabs, you can trigger a AJAX post or get from the event handler based on the tab and send the values of tab (am not sure what value you wanted to send). You can check how to do get/post from "http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/". Your question does not explain me what sort of response you are expecting from controller, so I cannot help you on that. Hope this helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
      activate: function(event ,ui){
        var $activeTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        if ($activeTab == 1) {
          alert("tab1");
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<body>    
  <div id="tabs" role="tabpanel">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" aria-controls="Active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Active</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabs-2" aria-controls="Inactive" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Inactive</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabs-3" aria-controls="Retired" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Retired</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" ></div>
      <div id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" ></div>
      <div id="tabs-3" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Now I'm actually getting feedback from my tabs, thank you. The controller side of things aren't going too well though. What I'm expecting out of my controller is to receive the value of the tab (the index will do as I can assign appropriate values in my controller). I then would like to use that value for creating an appropriate Model Attribute that is used on the same page (it's a list of values used to populate a table, the tabs determine which records to show). I would like to do this as well as keep the selected tab "selected" after I refresh the page.

Comment: If you are submitting the value using ajax, you can design your controller to return json response using @ResponseBody annotation. This is one of the option and use jquery success method to populate the data. As far as keeping the tab even after refresh, you may be able to do that using a javascript variable initialized whenever a tab is selected or using a query param etc. There are multiple options available. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[edited]
There's something in your HTML that's breaking the jQuery tabs code.

Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1r712od4/2/ - it works fine.

Try taking the unneeded `aria-controls` and classes from your code and trying again.

The JS you need is something like:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var activeTab = ui.newTab.data("tabid");
        if (activeTab == 1) {
            alert ("Tab 1!");
        }
    }
});
```

As for the Spring code, someone else will have to help you out with that!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've completed those steps but still don't see the alert window pop up.

Comment: I've edited the answer now that I can run the code. See if that helps.

Comment: Taking code from that fiddle, I exclude the tab content section because I don't need it and I end up with just a bullet list instead of tabs. Any ideas?